# How can i instantiate a class which is having private constructor

Tags: php

How can i instantiate a class which is having private constructor.?

I don't want to use any function inside the class to create its own instance.

Ex class is :

```
class Test extends Test2 implements Test3 {
   private function __construct () {
   }

   function doDisplay() {
   }

   function Docall() {
   }
}
```

Comment: I just used because OOP is not patent with any programming language.

Comment: Different languages implement OOP differently, and there is no S in OOP.

Comment: Yes only syntax matters ... But answer of this question won't be related to any programming language. That i just gave an example.

Comment: Syntax isn't the only thing that matters — Objective-C is an OO language but it has completely no notion of public or private constructors.

Answer (score 11):

You can instanciate it using Reflection (PHP >= 5.4)

```or-tag-here
class Test {

    private $a;

    private function __construct($a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass(Test::class);
$constructor = $class->getConstructor();
$constructor->setAccessible(true);
$object = $class->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
$constructor->invoke($object, 1);
```

It works, but keep in mind that this was not an usage that the class was designed for, and that it might have some unforeseen side effects.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to create a unit test for a singleton class with a private constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You can't invoke a private constructor from anywhere but within the class itself, so you *have* to use an externally-accessible static method to create instances.

Also, if `Test2` has a constructor that isn't private, you can't make `Test::__construct()` private.

Comment: Why i wanted to do this is because, i wanted to create objects only in some factory. I don't want others directly create object for this class. Is there any other way i can handle this ?

Comment: Well, classes are always globally accessible in PHP wherever you include them. You can have a public constructor that accepts the factory as an argument, and if it's not the factory object creating it then throw an exception.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot instantiate an object from a class whose constructor is `private` (out of syllabus).

If you are intend to use it's function, then you should have them as `static` and use them to fulfill your needs. Make sure that function is public.

For ex:

```
<?php

class something
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        echo "something";
    }

    public static function display($msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
    }
}

something::display("Testing...");

?>
```

See the working example: http://codepad.org/VoYeyk8W

Comment: Here I think we are not instantiating class its, instantiating is not possible

Comment: Exactly, that is the point here, you cannot instantiate a class but you can still call a `static` method.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever designed this class does not want you to instantiate one directly, you cannot do what you want to do.  Most likely the original author had a good reason for doing this, maybe it was memory management or he wanted to control the life cycle or stop problems with threading, it could be a lot of reasons.

The only obvious answer is to rewrite the sources so they work the way you want instead of trying to break into someone else's design.  Or you could build a wrapper around this class that hides away the part you don't like so the rest of you code doesn't have to know.

Comment: Can you explain me how it is related to memory management and treading?

Comment: @Sahal I believe Patrick assumed this to be a singleton class, which could be related to memory management - instead of having multiple (large) classes instantiated, you're forced to use a single, shared instance. Although threading isn't usually a concern in PHP, this could be related to threading concepts for a similar reason - instead of instantiating multiple instances that interact with the same resource, you're forced to use a single one that presumably cannot be used to do things out of order.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to use a (static) method inside the class to create an instance I guess the answer to your question simply is: you cannot.